# AngularJS binding a javascript object to a directive attribute

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have a problem when I try to bind a javascript object in an attribute of a directive.

I have a controller in which I make an $http.get request to a rest api service, i receive some data among which a JSON string representing an itinerary for a map canvas.

```
.controller('myController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope,$http) {
    $http.get(endpointUrl)
        .success(function(data){
            if(data.status == 'ok'){
                $scope.itinerary = angular.fromJson(data.itinerary);
            }
        });
}]);
```

If I log $scope.itinerary in console I see it's a valid javascript object

```
{"origin":"Piazza Adua, Firenze","destination":"Galleria degli Uffizi, Firenze","waypoints":[{"location":"Fiesole, Firenze","stopover":true},{"location":"Piazza Santa Croce, Firenze","stopover":true}],"optimizeWaypoints":false,"travelMode":"DRIVING"}
```

I need to bind that object in a directive attribute.

```
.directive('map', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            myItinerary: "="
        },
        templateUrl: 'templates/directive/map.html',
        link: function(scope,el,attrs) {
            console.log(attrs);
        }
    }
});
```

This is the HTML

```
<map my-itinerary="itinerary"></map>
```

When I log attrs inside the directive link function the attribute myItinerary is the string "itinerary" and not the object like i would expect.
I tried to interpolate itinerary with {{ }} but , as I would expect, this generate a Syntax Error.
I also tried to switch '=' with '@' and bind the json string instead of the javascript object but the value of attrs.myItinerary inside the directive is an empty string.
I saw many examples to bind an object to a directive and no one has a problem with the same approach i used. 
Since i started using angular recently I would like to know if my approach is wrong or why it does not work.
Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: `attrs` will only ever be the string value of all attributes. `$scope.myItinerary` will be the bound value. All bound values are available in the `link` method on your `$scope`

Comment: I tried to log scope.myItinerary inside the link function but the result is the same: the value is the string "itinerary" and not the object I stored in $scope.itinerary in the controller

Comment: If you do `console.log(scope.myItinerary)`, you will get the JavaScript object.

Comment: It can't be the string value if your not setting it. However it could be `undefined`, if it is the browser may not log it as such confusing the log?. That is because your `console.log` in the link will most likely run before the `$http` request has returned setting the data. Stick a button in your directive view and a click handler in the link to log the value. Then you can check after the AJAX request has returned.

Comment: @ste2425 you are right, if log scope.myItinerary after a little timeout i get the obj, so I have another question, since I need to pass that object to a google service to render the itinerary, how i can do that? It's better to make an http request for that obj inside the directive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Original Issue**

When you bind something to a directive that bound value is available on the `$scope` object. Not the `attrs` object.

So in the controller `$scope.controllerParam = 10`

and implemented in the view `<my-directive input="controllerParam"></my-directive>`

You could have a directive markup like so

```
.directive('myDirective', function () {
    return {
        restrict: E,
        scope: {
            input: '='
        },
        link: function ($scope, e, attrs) {
            console.log($scope.input); //Will log 10
            console.log(attrs.input); //Will log string controllerParam
        }
    }
});
```

**Updating content in your Link**

This is from your comments about data sourced from an API.

Your link function is run once when your directive first runs. That is why when you console.log your scope the value `myItinerary` is undefined as the AJAX call has not returned at that point. If you were to put the console.log in a timeout it would work as the AJAX request has returned and value updated through data-binding at that point. However that is a terrible idea for dealing with dynamic content like that.

**Watch**

If you need to perform some logic of a bound variable in your link function you can put a watch on it so that if it is changed inside or outside your directive your watch handler will fire.

```
$scope.$watch('myItinerary', function(newValue, oldValue) {
  console.log(newValue, oldValue);
});
```

However if your adding lots of these they can come at a performance hit as every watch is assessed every time a digest cycle is run, pluss handling that fact they can be triggered from changes inside or outside your directive can be tough to deal with.

**Services**

Generally speaking all your ajax requests should be defined in a service and injected into what ever needs them. So if a directive has a single purpose it is feasible that it could make that request itself by injecting the service directly into it.

**Binding a function**
Your directive could potentially also expose a function that your controller could bind to. When your controller has data it could call this function passing it data.

```
//View
<my-directive update="update"></my-directive>

//in controller simply do
$scope.update('new data');

//directive

.directive('myDirective', function () {
    return {
        restrict: E,
        scope: {
            update: '='
        },
        link: function ($scope, e, attrs) {
            $scope.update = function (d) {
                console.log(d);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

You have to be careful though if you try to call a bound function that hasn't been updated yet or if the directive has it as optional. In either case the bound variable in the controller would be undefined.

Out of them all in my opinion the service is best. Falling back to watches when a service is not suitable. I avoid exposing functions as it just feels wrong to me but its possible. To be fair i very rarely have a need to use watches in the stuff ive had to do.

Sorry for the essay

Comment: Thanks a lot for your complete answer.

Comment: I think you have a typo in the second example, the directive should be declared as `<my-directive update="update"></my-directive>`. If not specified explicitly, the attribute name would have the name of the scope variable in your directive definition.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a [sample](http://plnkr.co/edit/1RVbcN?p=preview) for hypen (`-`) based directive.

You have to make sure you are using

```
scope: { 
   myItinerary: "=myItinerary"
}
```

You can refer to the last example under [Creating a Directive that Wraps Other Elements](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-a-directive-that-wraps-other-elements) section in angularjs

Comment: As ste2425 suggested it's a problem of timing. The console.log  command run before http request response with the data. The strange thing is that if I do console.log(scope) inside the directive link function the property myItinerary is correctly set with the obj...for that reason I didn't think it could be a timing problem